# Stop, Hide or Strip out the title="" Attribute

Tags: javascript, wordpress

In the WordPress core code is a rule to auto-create `title=""` attributes for links whether it's desired or not.

There appear to be some out-dated plugins that attempt to fix this that are no longer working so instead what I'm hoping is that there is some JavaScript to either block `title=""` auto-creation altogether or strip it out.

The reason I want to block out titles is because I'm using CSS tooltips that are getting covered by the browser default tooltips... that are only there because of WP auto-created titles.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to strip it out?

Comment: What title attrs? In the WP menu? With images via the WP image uploader?

Comment: Technically speaking, the `title` attribute is required by the HTML 4.01 spec, empty or not. Not sure why you'd want to remove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of, let me say that I completely agree with Gavin - removing the title attribute is counterproductive in getting your HTML to validate. Also I do not see a reason why you'd want to remove it.

That being said, this javascript does what you want:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        var alinks = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
        for (var i = 0; i < alinks.length; i++) {
            alinks[i].removeAttribute("title"); 
        }
    }
</script>
```